# Gzip content in socket programming

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

With the following method, I can easily get the content of a website and pass it to client:

```
private void sendResponseToLocalClient() throws IOException {
  final DataOutputStream socketOutput = new DataOutputStream(this.socket.getOutputStream());
  if (remoteConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
     final DataInputStream remoteInput = new DataInputStream(remoteConnection.getInputStream());
     final byte[] data = new byte[(int) Short.MAX_VALUE];
     int index = remoteInput.read(data, 0, (int) Short.MAX_VALUE);
     while (index != -1) {
        socketOutput.write(data, 0, index);
        index = remoteInput.read(data, 0, (int) Short.MAX_VALUE);
     }
     socketOutput.flush();
  }
}
```

but when it comes to GZIP or deflate, the client's browser never recognize my response. 
example of what I call response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
null : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *
Vary : Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding : chunked
Date : Sat  18 Jun 2016 11:11:11 GMT
Expires : Sun  18 Jun 2017 11:11:11 GMT
Content-Encoding : gzip
Last-Modified : Tue  07 Oct 2014 11:52:45 GMT
Connection : keep-alive
Content-Type : application/x-javascript
Server : nginx/1.2.1
Cache-Control : max-age=31536000

GZIP Data
```

What should I do to handle such a situation?

Comment: Are these really spaces between key and colon in all your HTTP header lines, i.e. "Content-Encoding<space>:..."? If this would be the case then these are all invalid headers and it would be no wonder the client does not understand it.

Comment: yes they are spaces, but as I said, this procedure works for regular content types.

Comment: where do you actually compress your data in your code? You are supposed to use GZIPOutputStream for such need

Comment: data compression is occurring somewhere else, suppose my client wants to open `www.example.com` and this website use gzip compression. my application just plays the proxy role.

Comment: so show us the code where you compress your data in Java, otherwise how can we help?

Comment: @Khodabakhsh: some browsers accept these invalid spaces before the colon (Chrome, Edge, Opera, Safari), others don't (Firefox, IE).

Comment: @NicolasFilotto the problem is I'm not the one who is compressing the data, I receive it compressed.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich the browser is not changing. I only use chrome.

Comment: @Khodabakhsh: add a packet capture of what you send to the client to your question (use cloudshark.org) and one can take a look what is really going on. With the current information in your question it is impossible to say.